# C# WindowsForm DataGridView how to display double variable "0,1" as "0,10"

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a datagridview and a datatable that has a double variable column. I want to display datatable values which are between 0.1 to 0.9 as "0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4.." (i mean with one decimal value) on datagridview. And i want to display values which are greater than 0.9 as "0.10,0.11,0.12,....0.20". But datagridview displays and rounds 0.10, 0.20, 0.30 as 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 when user tries to change datagridview cell value. I know 0.1 and 0.10 are the same values. But i want to display values and allow to user change values as i mentioned.

My table is displayed on datagridview like below;

Data Versions

0,1

0,2

0,6

0,7

0,9

If user tries to increase last cell of column 0,9 to 0,10, datagridview displays 0,10 as 0,1. How can i manage this problem? Please help me.

Comment: Can you add the code that is doing the formatting to your question?

Comment: _f user tries to increase last cell of column 0,9 to 0,10_ -  0,10 is **less than** 0,9

Comment: You want to allow 0,1 and 0,10 in different cells of the same column? So take customer input as it?

Comment: @Ralf yes exactly i want to allow both 0,1 and 0,10.

Comment: In that case you need a string column and ignore it being a number and do input checking (and if its a feature of the grid sorting) yourself. You may be lucky when you use a decimal for that column. A decimal knows about the 0 at the end and can distinct 0,1 from 0,10 but i have no idea if the GridView Control handles that correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DefaultCellStyle` property of the column and set the `Format` property to "0.#" for values between 0.1 and 0.9 or "0.00" if the value is greater than or equal to 0.9 :

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    if (col.Name == "ColumnName")
    {
        col.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.#";
    }
}
```